# Get selection of non required field on introspection

Tags: graphql, introspection

I'm using GraphQL with Apollo Server and Client in JS and try to introspect my schema.

Simplified I have a schema like:

```
input LocationInput {
  lat: Float
  lon: Float
}

input CreateCityInput {
  name: String!
  location: LocationInput
}
```

I query this with an introspection like:

```
fragment InputTypeRef on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    inputFields {
      name
      type {
        name
        kind
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          inputFields {
            name
            type {
              name
              kind
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

query CreateCityInputFields {
  input: __type(name: "CreateCityInput") {
    inputFields {
      name
      description
      type {
        ...InputTypeRef
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As result I receive:

```
{
  "data": {
    "input": {
      "inputFields": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "description": "",
          "type": {
            "kind": "NON_NULL",
            "name": null,
            "ofType": {
              "kind": "SCALAR",
              "name": "String",
              "inputFields": null
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "location",
          "description": "",
          "type": {
            "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
            "name": "LocationInput",
            "ofType": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As one can see: `lat` and `lon` are missing. If I set `LocationInput` as required (`location: LocationInput!`) in `CreateCityInput` I receive the missing `lat` and `lon`.

How can I query for `lat` and `lon` without haven `LocationInput` required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had a wrong query for the introspection. Moving the `inputField` part out of `ofType` to the upper level fix the issue:

```
  kind
  name
  inputFields {
    name
    description
    type {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
      }
    }
  }
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    inputFields {
      name
      description
      type {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

query CreateCityInputFields {
  input: __type(name: "CreateCityInput") {
    inputFields {
      name
      description
      type {
        ...InputTypeRef
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Solved the issue.